# Why is there only a single implementation of mining pool software?

Tags: mining-pools

Every pool in Monero looks the same and uses the same software. Why is this?

Comment: There are at least three pool implementations, though the ones used by dwarfpool and minergate are, to my knowledge, closed source (caveat user).

Answer (score 4):

Lack of different implementation may look like lack of interest but in this case its most certainly that the current implementation by [zone117x](https://github.com/zone117x/node-cryptonote-pool) going solid for 2+ years and the first open-source for CryptoNote coins is good enough. There is another pool software implementation being run by [Minergate](https://minergate.com/) but the client and server-side is closed-source.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the node.js implementation and forks of that, there is also a Golang implementation. I don't know if it is currently in use, but I believe it has been used before.

https://github.com/sammy007/go-cryptonote-pool